# Equation with Matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

i am working on a paper regarding Mortality Modeling. I have the following equation and I can't figure out why the following equation holds. I think the background knowledge is not important, it's normal matrix multiplication and $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. If someone can give me a hint that would be awesome!

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I solved the Matrix Exponential using Wolfram Alpha:
[image]

Normal multiplication leads to result. Thanks for the answers in the comment section!

Comment: Have you tried to calculate that [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)? If not please do so and add the attempt to your question.

Comment: Denote by $A$ the exponent in the matrix exponential. Direct calculation shows that $e^A=e^{-b\tau}[A+(b\tau+1)I]$. The rest follows from usual matrix-vector multiplications.